# Debugging Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

Visual studio only displays the last value of the variable not all the values as it changes:

[image: Screen Shot of the problem]

Comment: You should move your breakpoint  to line 73 to see the `X` value change.

Comment: it returns 0 when i break it on line 73 .. one value

Comment: The first time it should be 0, but you can use F10 to execute the code line by line and see its changing.

Comment: thanks but could you tell me how can i see all the variables in the data tip or the autos .. that would really be of a big help

Comment: This article might help you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/07/15/7-ways-to-look-at-the-values-of-variables-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/

Comment: Thank you , that was informative

Comment: @ahmed elbarky, In debug window(local or watch or others), you couldn't view all values for this loop, you need to debug your app using "Step Into(F11)", and then you could view them one by one, whether this issue has been resolved? If it was resolved, you could post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it was suggested in the comments going through the debugging process step by step (F11) should be used and to go through only the loop in the program i should use (F10)